# Preprocessor Definitions - Prompt on Build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

At my company we have a large C++ project with multiple features that can be enabled or disabled with various preprocessor definitions.

If we were to enumerate each of the possible preprocessor/feature combinations in a list of Project Configurations, we'd have ourselves quite an extensive list (not to mention long configuration names)!

Is there a plug-in - or some other unknown feature - which can display a prompt when a user initiates a build, such that the user can check/uncheck a list of configurable features, in order to enable or disable the preprocessor definitions?

Something like this would be awesome:

[image]

Comment: That would be nasty for the Nightly Build. Which developer has to stay late?

Comment: That's a valid point; it would probably have to display only if the Project Configuration is set to "Custom," or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple application which will produce a header file with defines

```
#ifndef __GEN_CONFIG__
#define __GEN_CONFIG__

#undef  LOGGING
#define LOGGING 1 // for example

#undef  FEATURE_A
#define FEATURE_A 0

#endif
```

this header can then be included in the project.

The application/dialog can be executed as a [Visual Studio Pre-Build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), to ensure that the header file is updated right before compilation.

Comment: I'm familiar with pre- and post-build events, but I'm not sure if you can use them to modify preprocessor definitions.

If you CAN modify preprocessor definitions from within the pre-build step, then there could be a really hacky way to manually display a Windows Forms prompt and pipe the results into the pre-build step.  But honestly, my question is really aimed more at finding a configurable plugin which may already exist, to avoid all this extra hack-around.

Comment: IMHO there is nothing 'hacky' to create simple app which produces trivial header file with `#define`s and this header file can then be easily included.

Comment: That may be the solution I try out, but I'll leave the question open for some more time before I mark yours as correct.  Another example of the old adage: "If you want something done right..."

Comment: Also, would you mind updating your answer to actually include the steps you described in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use CMake for exactly this task. In a `CMakeLists.txt` you can use the command `set(<variable> <value> CACHE <type> <docstring>)`, which creates a variable and puts it in the CMake cache with a given documentation string. You can then use tools such as `ccmake` to edit these values. If you made the value a boolean, you can switch features on or off for example.

On windows, you can view and edit the cache entries with a [gui](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html), which is similar to the dialog box you have posted in the question.

**Edit:** CMake does not bring up a popup when you create a build. Instead it remembers the variables in a cache. The usual way is to have different builds with different features, i.e. you could have one build in debug mode with all features, another one in release mode with a minimal feature set only and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my analysis tool that builds the list of all preprocessor keys that are used in the project. http://cdsan.com/Samp_CondParams.php

Besides building the list itself it makes a classification of those params.